# If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and positive, is it necessarily the case that a prime appears along the line $ax+b$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If not, can we weaken the result? For example, if $n$ is some random positive integer, is it necessarily the case that a number relatively prime to $n$ appears along the line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "yes", there are infinitely many primes on the line $ax + b$ for natural $x$. This is called [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). In fact, the different lines for all the different possible $b$'s (less than $a$ and coprime to $a$) all have roughly the same relative density of primes.

More specifically, given any such line $ax + b$, and a bound $X$, then as $X$ grows the number of primes below $aX + b$ divided by the number of primes on the line for $0\leq x\leq X$ converges to $\varphi(a)$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function (i.e. $\varphi(a)$ is the total number of non-overlapping lines).

Although $b$'s that are not squares modulo $a$ do get a few more primes than the ones that are (a phenomenon called Chebychev's bias), this effect is not strong enough to affect relative densities.